# Getting syntax error using the Lead/Lag function in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm new to using the Lead/Lag function in SQL Server 2012 and I got the syntax error when I tested it in SQL Server Management Studio. I used the lead and lag function for the purpose of fetching previous and next row values.

SQL Syntax I used:

```
SELECT 
    Id, Name, Address, Age, Nationality,
    LEAD(Name, 1) OVER (ORDER BY Id ) LeadValue,
    LAG(Name, 1) OVER (ORDER BY Id ) LagValue
FROM 
    Table
```

Error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.

Please advise what I've missed here. Thanks

Comment: Try wrapping the word `table` in brackets like this: `[table]`. `Table` is a reserved word in T-SQL for the sake of commands like `alter table ..`, or `drop table ...`.

Comment: The same you wouldn't call a variable with the name `function` in any language, you shouldn't call a table `table`. Though legal, it is 180 degrees from best practices.

Comment: @tarheel -  After I wrapped my table object like this [Table], it doesn't return any values. It returns null. Do I need to rename my table? Any thoughts?

Comment: @FDavidov - Are you suggesting to rename my table and put bracket on the syntax?

Comment: If you rename your table from, say,  `Table` to `MyTable` you will not need the `[]`. The `[]` in your case are used to tell the compiler that **table** is a name and not a keyword in this case.

Comment: @FDavidov - Why it doesn't return any values after I put bracket on my table object?

Comment: @timmack Are there records available in `[table]`? If so, we may need more clarification in the question of example records. To expand on @FDavidov's point, given the column names listed a better name would be something like `lkup_person`, to both avoid reserved words, and give end users an idea of what data the table holds.

Comment: It would help if you provide the updated query along with some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Standard debugging method: Start with a `select` without conditions and see that you get results; then, add one condition at the time and see which causes an empty result. This is the only answer you can get now before you share some data.

Comment: @FDavidov I got it working now. However, it returns all the data in the table along with their Lead and Lag Value column. How do I do it if I just want to return two rows which are the previous and next row of the selected row? Do I need to use Where clause on this? or do I need to set with parameter value for the Name column?

Comment: The purpose of the `WHERE` clause is exactly that, filter out unwanted results (or, filter in ONLY the wanted results, if any).

Comment: @FDavidov - How? Can you translate your comments into sample SQL code based on the given code I presented?

Comment: Your table has 5 fields, namely `Id, Name, Address, Age, Nationality`. You can use any combination of them to set the filter, for instance: `WHERE Age > 18 AND Nationality IN ('US','UK','FR','IT')`. For a more focused answer, you will need to post sample data from your table and the expected result (based on the posted sample data).

Answer (score 2):

Table is `keyword`. Please avoid to use *reserved words* and *keywords*.

If your table have name Table, add brackets like [Table].

List of reserved words and keywords: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822(v=sql.110).aspx

Second task in comment:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Tmp') is not null drop table #Tmp
select *, row_number() over (order by Id) RN
into #Tmp
from [Table] 

select t.* 
from #Tmp t, (select Id, max(RN) mx, min(RN) mi from #Tmp group by Id) f
where t.Id = f.Id
    and (f.mx = t.RN or f.mi = t.RN)
```

Comment: I got it working now. However, it returns all the data in the table along with their Lead and Lag Value column. How do I do it if I just want to return two rows which are the previous and next row of the selected row? Do I need to use Where clause on this? or do I need to set with parameter value for the Name column?

Comment: Lag and Lead get values in order by clause and only add new column, does not filter data. For filtering you have to use where clause or join. But you can use row_number too. Insert into temp table with row_number() over (order by Id) and select min and max from this new column.

Comment: To make it clearer. Can u please change your answer as to which your comments suggested?Thanks

Comment: It should be separate quetion, maybe some editor will split it. Added.